# for-loop gets stuck on the same number

Tags: javascript

Below loop runs once for i=0, then indefinitely for i=1 into a browser crash, i.e. i does not increment:

```
cascadeComponent: function(item, fn, scope) {
    if (fn.call(scope || this, item) !== false) {
        if (item.items) {
            for (i = 0; i < item.items.items.length; i++) {
                this.cascadeComponent(item.items.items[i], fn, scope);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can avoid the issue by using the frameworks iteration loop. Alternatively I have the same loop working with the slight difference that the array is found in item.items vs. item.items.items.

Any ideas why that happens? It's the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: are your sure its `item.items.items.length` or `item.items.length`..please show us what you have in item....

Comment: Yes, that's the structure Ext.js uses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a global `i` variable. Add this line at the start of the function:

```
var i;
```

Otherwise each recursive call resets `i` to 0 for all invocations of `cascadeComponent`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Completely missed it. Sometimes too much staring at a problem doesn't help and a fresh view is required :)